# Transactions with Prepared Statements fails

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, transactions

I try to use `transactions` with `prepared statements`in order to update table `INVENTORY` where :

```
CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" (
    "product" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "lot" VARCHAR,
    "barcode" VARCHAR,
    "quantity" INTEGER,

    PRIMARY KEY ("barcode")
);
```

What I want to do is to insert a new row, but if in my table a row exists with the same primary key then to update it by adding the old value + the new.

I read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) and [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/) and I think I followed the instructions right.

```
String sqInsert = "INSERT INTO INVENTORY VALUES ('100541026044','01','301610101','10054102604401301610101','5000')";
String sqUpdate = "UPDATE INVENTORY set quantity = quantity + 5000 where barcode='10054102604401301610101'";

// transaction block start   
c.setAutoCommit(false);         

stm = c.prepareStatement(sqInsert);    
System.out.println("try to insert");
result = stm.executeUpdate();

System.out.println("try to update");
stm = c.prepareStatement(sqUpdate);
result = stm.executeUpdate();

c.commit(); //transaction block end
System.out.println("Done!");
```

In my table a row with `barcode=10054102604401301610101` exists, so I want the update to be executed. However, I get

```
try to insert
Error inserting products :[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: INVENTORY.barcode)
```

*Note: (I don't set the values from query, but with `stm.setString(1, "string");`) I just want to be short the code here*

Comment: You are executing both the insert and the update. (And if the insert succeeds, you then update the new row.) You need an if/else.

Comment: @CL. Are you sure that both queries are executed? If yes why I don't get in console the message `try to update` ?

Comment: I reversed the queries first the update and then the insert and it worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will fail due to a duplicated primary key on the bar code.
First do the update

```
stm = c.prepareStatement(sqUpdate);
result = stm.executeUpdate();
```

Then check the value of result which will be the number of rows affected by the update. If it is zero then the product with given barcode didn't exist so after the update do

```
if (0==result) {
    stm = c.prepareStatement(sqInsert);    
    stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

You'll want to put everything under a try {} catch {} to avoid a resource leak or leaving the connection unusable

```
try {
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    stm = c.prepareStatement(sqUpdate);
    result = stm.executeUpdate();
    if (0==result) {
        stm.close();
        stm = null;
        stm = c.prepareStatement(sqInsert);    
        stm.executeUpdate();
        stm.close();
        stm = null;
    }
    c.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if (stm!=null) stm.close();
    c.rollback();
}
```